# Default option for Select not working (reactive form)

Tags: angular

I'm trying to set the default value for a `Select` in a Reactive form, but not having any luck. I saw a lot of discussion on this topic in Stackoverflow, and it seems all I need to do is add `[selected]="(expression)"` but the solutions haven't worked for me. What am I doing wrong?

```
// Note: itm[6] == ["Option1", "Option2, "Option3"], itm[5]=="Option2" (i.e., the default)

<select name="foo" formControlName="foo">
  <option *ngFor="let g of itm[6]; let idx = index" [value]="idx" [selected]="g==itm[5]">{{g}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with reactive form you can did this by set the form control itself rather than try set the select attribute , any change of the value of the form control will reflect to the html , her any change of the value will set the option to be selected and in case the value was not in the option will look like empty.

```
this.form.get('foo').setValue('Option2')
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formcontrol-getter-setter-9sgdjj)

Comment: Many thanks. As below, I've tried everything, but it's still not working. I also tried your syntax as above instead of patchValue. Can `setValue` or `patchValue` be called at any time after the control is created in the component?

Comment: I will create a demo for you

Comment: @Crowdpleasr I have update my answer with live demo , hope  this will help 

Comment: Thank you, and @Armin for your answers. It turns out that my problem was as per my original post I had: `[value]=idx`, so I either needed to change that to `[value]=g` or else use the index number in `setValue` or `patchValue`

Answer (score 2):

You can try by adding [selected]="g==='Option2'" to select option. Or you can patch default value to formcontrol

this.myForm.patchValue({
     foo : 'Option2'
});

Comment: Many thanks. I tried that, but it's still not working. I put the code in ngOnInit (and I also tried it in ngAfterContentInit). Because I'm using an async service to grab the data that goes into the <select>, I tried putting the patch as far down the code as possible, in case there's a timing issue. But nothing is working. Any further ideas?

Comment: if you are patching the value to form control then you do not need the [selected] in option. After patching value you need to implement change detection.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that my problem was as per my original post I had: `[value]=idx`, so I either needed to change that to `[value]=g` or else use the index number in `setValue` or `patchValue`